# How to combine TF-IDF weights with BERT embeddings?

Tags: bert-language-model, tf-idf

I'm trying to implement the approach suggested by this [paper](https://aclanthology.org/2020.semeval-1.35.pdf). In their words
"We apply the TF-IDF score in the BERT mask layer, making the different attention score for the embedding crossing" and "through the attention mechanism of BERT model, we converted the distance between two words at any position to 1, which effectively solves the difficult long-term dependence problem in NLP. So we can directly use the feature representation of BERT as the word embedding feature of the following task."

I can't figure out where exactly TF-IDF comes into play. Should I use weights on the model output, or should I build the model from scratch and feed TF-IDF there?

The end goal is to cluster twitter users based on their sentence embeddings to detect their stances (as suggested by Rasheed et. al., [article](https://ojs.aaai.org/index.php/ICWSM/article/view/18082)).